# Declaring an array as an instance, or an member.

Tags: java

You can't do the codes below for some reason, but you can do it in a method. Why?

```
public class Frame {
String text [] = new String[];
}
```

Comment: You can't do it in either. It is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning a size to your array. Arrays in Java have a fixed size that must be supplied when creating them. So, if you wanted an array that could store 10 elements, you'd use:

```
String[] text = new String[10];
```

Substitute 10 for whatever size it is you need. If you don't know the size, or need the size to be able to change, consider using a `List<>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

See some tutorial before: [Java Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Your declaration is syntactically incorrect, It should be:

```
String text [] = new String[0]; // 0-> size you want for your array
```

For more details (Answer for Comment): From [JLS-15.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)

```
ArrayCreationExpression: 
new PrimitiveType DimExprs [Dims] 
new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs [Dims] 
new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer

DimExprs:
DimExpr {DimExpr}
DimExpr:
{Annotation} [ Expression ]
```

> The type of each dimension expression within a DimExpr must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to an integral type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: you didn't need to add the zero if you declared it in a method. it only show up as an error when you declare it as a class variable. But thanks.

Comment: 0 is just for example, if you see the comment along with it. The Point is your declaration is syntactically incorrect. See the link for more details

Comment: No. I mean if you don't put any numbers in the array size declaration, and if you declared it in a method, it doesn't show up as an error, but it's still incorrect. However, if you declared it as a class variable, the error does show up. That was what i was trying to say. But it's working now. Thanks.

Comment: inside function it still give you "Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer" error, nevertheless see the answer for more details.